# Sending an email in phone

Tags: javascript, ajax, email

I am trying to create a mobile app in which I need to send an email with attachment (both single and multiple).

I tried in android but i want a code that will support both android and ios.
I tried for javascrpit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
             + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
             + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value)
    ;

    window.location.href = link;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="sendMail(); return false">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

but it opens the outlook 2000 and it won't work for phone, I require something that opens the gmail app in the phone with the sender as the currently logged in id and the receiver's id to be added dynamically.

I tried in java as well but it does not work in client side as I will have to send some attachment in it in future.

Suggest anything that will work.

Thanks.. :)

Comment: Warning: The `escape()` function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5.

Comment: How about simply creating a [`mailto:` anchor tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197430/how-to-set-anchor-tag-mailto-attribute-in-webview-android)?

Comment: @Cerbrus won't it open the outlook and that i guess will not work in phone nicely....i am a newbiee in this....

Comment: A mailto link will open whatever email software the device uses.

Comment: @Cerbrus and what if i just want to open the gmail app ???

Comment: Not everyone has the gmail app.

Comment: sorry i missed a detail...i want to add the receiver dynamically..

Answer (score 0):

Use Java-Mail jar (JMAPI). Create a temporary email file (.eml) and add the attachment, subject, to, body using MimeMessage to .eml file and open that file using Runtime.getRuntime.exec(). This will open the default email client with sender will be a logged in user.

Note: "mailto:" URI will not work with attachment as the support for attachment has been removed from mailto.